# Vim is not seeing these curly braces as valid? It works in Xcode

Tags: c, vim

[image: picture of the picture of the problem]

What is the reason for vim not seeing the braces, when it works in Xcode?

Comment: The syntax file probably does not support braces at this place. Check `:echo synIDattr(synID(<linenr>,<colnr>,1),"name")` replacing line and column numbers, and delve into the syntax file to understand..

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out which syntax group causes the highlighting. `:syn list` shows all active groups, but it's easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin. When you have the name of the offending syntax group, you can investigate where it comes from; (the last lines of) `:scriptnames` may help.

Some syntax plugins can be configured, e.g. whether to display errors, or the particular dialect to use. As most syntaxes are not accompanied by documentation, it's best to directly check in the source code, usually at `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/{filetype}.vim`. If you think the highlighting is wrong, contact the author; the email address usually can be found in the plugin's header.